# how to Connect two pc with single Wamp server

Tags: networking, wamp, server

Actually we are developing a new website in PHP . So is it possible to create a environment where we can share our works done .

> > > in simple One wamp and two pc connected with lan is possible or not ? if it is how??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your VHOST definition there should be a `<Directory ......</Directory>` parameter

Inside that add

### If you are using Apache 2.2.x

```
    Allow from 192.168.1
```

### If you are using Apache 2.4.x

```
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

This will allow any ip address starting with 192.168.1 to connect to that VHOST

If you want to be specific and only allow certain ip's you can use this instead

```
Allow from 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11
```

Or, if youare using Apache 2.4

```
Require ip 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.11
```

So your VHOST should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/countlead" 
   ServerName domain.com 
   ServerAlias www.domain.com
   <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/countlead">
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
      Require ip 192.168.2
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: @KAKULSARMA that is just a foldername. Replace that with any folder name of your choice that matches your project name.

Answer (score -1):

if run xampp or wamp (apache), and If Dmz (modem option) Forward packet to pc that wamp is run on it (LAN IP Address: exp:192.168.x.x) You Can Use His Remote Ip address To See (wamp/xampp) Root Directory .

Comment: Showing Error <br /> Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

Comment: We are Adding this on Vhost 
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    DocumentRoot "192.168.1.6/xampp/htdocs/countlead"
    ServerName domain.com

</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Use of the DMZ is **Very dangerous** and should only be considered if you actually know what you are doing.